# separate data from one column to 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

I have three columns viz **Name**, **Value**,  **Valueid**.

I need to split the contents of **value** into two columns **Valueof1** and **Valueof2** based on the remaining two columns. **Valueid** has only two values either 1 or 2.

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═════════╗
║ Name  ║ Value ║ Valueid ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╣
║ test1 ║   132 ║       1 ║
║ test2 ║   322 ║       2 ║
║ test3 ║   342 ║       1 ║
║ test1 ║   433 ║       2 ║
║ test2 ║   123 ║       1 ║
║ test3 ║   244 ║       2 ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═════════╝
```

I'd like to see that data displayed like this:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ Name  ║ Value ║ Valueid ║ Valueof1 ║ Valueof2 ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ test1 ║   132 ║       1 ║      132 ║      433 ║
║ test2 ║   322 ║       2 ║      123 ║      322 ║
║ test3 ║   342 ║       1 ║      342 ║      244 ║
║ test1 ║   433 ║       2 ║      132 ║      433 ║
║ test2 ║   123 ║       1 ║      123 ║      322 ║
║ test3 ║   244 ║       2 ║      342 ║      244 ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: What you're looking for is called pivoting. Since you don't give us any details, please review other Q&A under the [Pivot tag](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pivot?sort=votes&pageSize=50). You may find a solution there.

Answer (score 1):

sample data

```
;DECLARE @Data Table(Name  VARCHAR(20), Value INT, Valueid  INT
)
;INSERT INTO @Data
SELECT 'test1', 132, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'test2', 322, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'test3', 342, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'test1', 433, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'test2', 123, 1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'test3', 244, 2
```

Sql script

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT Name,[1] AS Value1,[2] AS Value2 FROM
    (
    SELECT * FROM @Data
    ) AS SRC
    PIVOT
    (
    MAX(Value) FOR Valueid IN([1],[2])
    )
    AS Pvt
)

SELECT c.Name,
       d.Value,
       d.Valueid,
       c.Value1,
       c.Value2 
FROM CTE c
RIGHT Join @Data d
ON c.Name=d.Name
```

Expected Result http://rextester.com/AYGM10195

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ Name  ║ Value ║ Valueid ║ Valueof1 ║ Valueof2 ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ test1 ║   132 ║       1 ║      132 ║      433 ║
║ test2 ║   322 ║       2 ║      123 ║      322 ║
║ test3 ║   342 ║       1 ║      342 ║      244 ║
║ test1 ║   433 ║       2 ║      132 ║      433 ║
║ test2 ║   123 ║       1 ║      123 ║      322 ║
║ test3 ║   244 ║       2 ║      342 ║      244 ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your sample data something like:

```
select x.name, x.value, x.valueid
     , min(y.value) as Valueof1
     , max(y.value) as Valueof2 
from t as x 
join t as y 
    on x.name = y.name 
group by x.name, x.value, x.valueid
```

should work

Comment: all the data is in a single table and the name of the table is Table1. Can you please help me get the query with the table name.                                   Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: replace t with Table1 in my query. If that don't work, please edit your question with `CREATE TABLE` statements and `INSERT` statements for sample data.